# Check if a data row of a data table is contained in another datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a dataset DS which contains one data table and the data table has several datarows.

I have another data set DS1 which contains one datatable and the datatable has one  datarow.

I would like to check if DS contains the row in DS1

The DataRow is of the following format :

```
Id Description
```

Currently I am doing the following :

```
   if (!(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Contains(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0])))
```

It throws an error like :

```
.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException: Table doesn't have a primary key.
```

Is there any other way to do it ?

For example

Dataset DS contains a Datatable :

```
1  ABC
2  DEF
3  GHI
```

Dataset DS1 contains a datatable :

```
1 ABC
```

I would like to see if the Row in datatable of DS1 is contained in the row of a datatable in DS

Comment: What do you mean Contains? All the value in row are equal?

Comment: Dataset cannot contains data row but a Datatable

Comment: I just edited my question .. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Same datarows cannot be found in more than one `DataTable`. are you looking for equal values?

Comment: Yes . I am looking for equal values. Can I see if a column in one data row is equal to columns in another data rows ?  I just updated my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this goal is:

DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("ID = " + ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());

Notice that only the ID field is being used to find matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
    bool CompareDataSets(DataSet ds1, DataSet ds2)
    {
        foreach (var dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0].Equals(dr)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm not sure it will work, just trying to help.